# How to change the color of drop down list view inside a WebView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, webview

```
  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@style/WebTheme"
    android:theme="@style/WebViewTheme" />

    <style name="WebTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

when i give text color black in style
low end device - text color- black , list view background -black, so it cannot be seen
other devices -   text color- white , list view background -black, so it can be seen
nexus 7 - text color- white , list view background -black, so it can be seen

when i give text color white in style
low end device - text color- white, list view background -black, so it can be seen
other devices -   text color- white , list view background -black, so it can be seen
nexus 7 - text color- black, list view background -black, so it cannot be seen

Comment: Well, this is just DHTML, not Android. Not directly, at least. I guess you'll have to use some JavaScript and/or some CSS.

Comment: Just create a HTML file and CSS file. Change the color in the CSS file

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve this problem is I wrap the html I want to include the text color:

```
String html = "<body style=\"color:white;margin:0;padding:0;" +
                "line-height:150%\"><div style=\"color:white;\">" + text + "</div></body>";
```

The "text" variable in this case is the html you want to display.  Everything else is just styling of that text.

Comment: actualy i want to change the text color of the list view .. so for list in web view how can we do it @tim.paetz

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  Use html to change style of the html.

Comment: I have a list of names ... i am displaying it in my web view as a drop down list.. i need to change the color of the text in this drop down list @tim.paetz

Comment: You need to share more code.  Update your question with everything relevant to what you need.